# Subtitles given to video in React are not accessible to NVDA screen reader

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

This is the code that I am using to show a help video.

```
<video src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/videos/guestHelpVideo.mp4'} width='100%' height='auto' controls>
    <track
        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/videos/help-video-subtitles.vtt'}
        label='English'
        kind='subtitles'
        srcLang='en'
        default
    />
</video>
```

The subtitles are visible on Chrome / Firefox

However NVDA screen reader is not able to read out the subtitles when video is played.

What change should I make so that NVDA screen reader can access and display those subtitles?

I tried removing src attribute and adding it in a different tag as suggested in a comment. It did not work

```
<video width='100%' height='auto' controls>
    <source src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/videos/guestHelpVideo.mp4'} type='video/mp4' />
    <track
        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/videos/help-video-subtitles.vtt'}
        type='text/vtt'
        label='English'
        kind='captions'
        srcLang='en'
        default
    />
</video>
```

Comment: Put the `<source>` element within the `<video>` element, it can be inconsistent if you declare it via a `src` attribute on `<video>`. See the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video#modifications_to_the_html_and_css. Also be sure to add `type` to the video `<source>` when you do it this way and double check your headers for the `.vvt` extension are correct mime type (`text/vtt`).

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I tried this, Still same issue

Comment: I have never seen captions or subtitle text be "focusable" elements with screen readers. You specifically mention NVDA. Does that mean JAWS and VoiceOver (Mac) **do** allow you to access the subtitles but NVDA does not?

Comment: @slugolicious No, Currently NVDA is the only screen reader I am able to test this with.

Comment: Ok. I don’t think any screen reader has access to subtitles or captions. You’d have to provide a transcript for screen readers.